# Python sort a list by value of a dict inside the list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a List and inside the list i got a dict and i want to sort the list by a value of the dict.

How does this work?

```
[{'id': 0, 'thread': 'First', 
 'post': [
           {'id': 0, 'title': 'MyPost', 'time': '2015-11-07 01:06:08.939687'}]
}, 
 {'id': 1, 'thread': 'Second', 
 'post': [
           {'id': 0, 'title': 'MyPost', 'time': '2015-11-07 01:06:42.933263'}]}, 
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'NoPosts', 'post': []}]
```

I would like to sort my Threadlist by time of the first post, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass sort or sorted a key function:

```
In [11]: def key(x):
             try:
                 return x["post"][0]["time"]   # return ISO date string
             except IndexError:
                 return "Not a date string"    # any letter > all date strings

In [12]: sorted(d, key=key)
Out[12]:
[{'id': 0,
  'post': [{'id': 0, 'time': '2015-11-07 01:06:08.939687', 'title': 'MyPost'}],
  'thread': 'First'},
 {'id': 1,
  'post': [{'id': 0, 'time': '2015-11-07 01:06:42.933263', 'title': 'MyPost'}],
  'thread': 'Second'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'NoPosts', 'post': []}]
```

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `return float('NaN')` for the `# NaN > all date strings` to be true? Then you loose Python 3 support...

Comment: The desired behavior for a post with no `time` was unspecified, so `'NaN'` sounds fine.

Comment: But `"NaN"` is just a string. It needs to be `float('NaN')` actually be the number `nan`. And Python3 will throw `TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()`  It should be either a space character or tilde in ASCII for string comparisons.

Comment: Well, the other values are strings too, so the `'NaN'` values will simply be at the end of this asciibetical sort. Ideally, those date strings would be stored as `datetime` objects.

Comment: @dawg - I know they aren't `datetime` objects - I said _ideally_ they would be in that format, because they are dates/times. However, if ISO 8601 can properly sort asciibetical strings, I really don't see the problem with including `'NaN'` at one end of the correctly-sorted list instead of the other.

Comment: I suppose. I do realize that `'0', '9'` all sort less than `'NaN'` but it is ambiguously stated is all.

Comment: Yes; as I said above, the question never said what to do with dateless entries, so putting those at one end of the list instead of the other doesn't seem to matter in the slightest.

Comment: @dawg I was doing this on python 3 (It's 2015 :p)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yup these are strings, whilst they're strings 'NaN' work ok, it's hack I think but should do the job in this case :) I hate to leave otherwise would have replied at the time - didn't realise it would be so contentious :s

Comment: @dawg which is to say, if I returned float('nan') this would raise on python 3, not sure what the ordering is on python 2 - probably makes no difference.